# CSS styling is being lost when lis are dynamically added to a ul

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to dynamically add links to a page but my css styling is only being applied to the list items the first time the list is created after each reload.

Below is my html:

```
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="selectConfirmation">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
        <a class="cancelSelectConfirmationBtn ui-btn-left" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left"  data-theme="b">Back</a>
        <h1>
          Confirmation Events
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" style="font-size: 16px;">
      <ul id="eventList" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview"></ul>
      </div>      
      </div>
```

and here is the portion of my java script that is adding the links:

function createList(ceg){

var list = document.getElementById('eventList');

```
for(i=ceg.length-1,k=0; k<ceg.length; i--,k++){
 var check = ceg.charAt(i);

 if(check == 1){
  var events = configJSON.root.DynamicDef.Application.SB_Primary.add[k]["-Data"].split(";");
  var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = '<a> ' + events[1] + '</a>';
  li.setAttribute('class', 'selectConfirmation');
  li.setAttribute('confirmcode', '5');
  li.setAttribute('data-theme', 'c');
  list.appendChild(li);
 }
}
var $list = $(list);
if ($list.hasClass('ui-listview')) {//this listview has already been initialized so refresh it
    $list.listview('refresh');
} else {//this list needs to be initialized
    $list.trigger('create');
}
```

gotoConfirmation();
}

Does anyone know why the css styling is being dropped when i recreate the list?

Comment: To clarify, you state that `my css styling is only being applied to the list items the first time`; do you mean that your `selectConfirmation` class is not being applied or that the jQuery Mobile classes/styles are not being applied?

Comment: The JQuery Mobile classes/styles are not being applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly after your `for` loop you can add this code that will check to see if the `listview` has been initialized by the jQuery Mobile framework:

```
var $list = $(list);
if ($list.hasClass('ui-listview')) {//this listview has already been initialized so refresh it
    $list.listview('refresh');
} else {//this list needs to be initialized
    $list.trigger('create');
}
```

This requires you to remove the `ui-listview` class from your `<ul>` tag so you can use it as a flag as to whether or not the jQuery Mobile framework has initialized the `listview`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PQ39n/15/

**UPDATE**

You stated in a comment that you get this error:

> Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'refresh'"

You get this error because you are trying to `refresh` a list that has not yet been initialized. My code above will help fix this problem since it checks whether or not the `listview` has been initialized and runs the proper code based on the state of the `listview`.

This is a common problem for developers who are new to jQuery Mobile because there are so many different events to bind to (`pageshow`, `pagecreate`, `pageinit`, etc.) and the `listview` widget may or may not be initialized yet at the time any of those events fire.

Comment: Thank you. This solution has solved my issue. I have updated the above code to the working version.

Answer (score 1):

Mannually adding class name is not enough since jQuery Mobile creates enhanced markup for each list item. You need to refresh your list triggering corresponding event. Add this code after your for-loop:

```
$(list).listview('refresh');
```

See [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html)

Comment: you should not assume that the OP wants answer in jquery, he has not tagged jquery.

Comment: It's obvious to anyone who has used jQueryMobile that the HTML above IS jQueryMobile. This is the correct answer.

Comment: sorry but the part of code he has provided i dont find even single char of jquery and i wont suggest to use jquery just for this.

Comment: Sorry I did not tag JQueryMobile but I am using it. I have tried $(list).listview('refresh');--which throws the error "Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'". I also tried $('#list').listview('refresh'); -- which also does not work.

Comment: First of all remove `class="ui-listview"` as JQM will add it itself. Then after initialization of this page call `$('#list').listview();`.

Comment: What can also cause the problem it's if you try to create entire list with your `createList` function. In this case you don't need to refresh list, but only create. So you would just add after `var list = document.getElementById('eventList');` this line `$(list).listview();`.